# How to create a hyperlink dynamically and placed it on another web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I am a newbie, currently working on ASP.net. I have two web pages, (A and B). I want to  dynamically create a hyperlink on **page A (A.aspx)** and the hyperlink should be **displayed** on **page B (B.aspx)**. How to do this? Badly need help. :(

Comment: you can not, unless save `page A's` hyperlinks in database or somewhere, and in `page B`, read hyperliks from where they have been saved

Comment: can you show your default url where you run your project

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a hyperlink dynamically in PageA and display it in PageB. I don't know when you are going to redirect to PageB but assuming that will happen in PageA; you can pass a QueryString parameter indicating that PageB should display the hyperlink. And create or show hidden hyperlink in PageB code behind, say Page_Load.

Forgive me for being unable to present sample code and also for formatting. Answering from mobile.

Comment: oh. I see. how to pass a querystring parameter then?

Comment: String added at the end of the url. It's very simple just google it. Also google how to get QueryString values in ASP.NET. you'll need it in PageB